# Trigger on Opportunity to update User object

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, user-record

Trigger on Opportunity to update User object

I need to make a trigger on the opportunity object that Adds +1 to a custom filed on the user object every time an opportunity that the user owns has the "Date qualified" field changed from null to having a date.

What I am trying to do is get a count on the user object of how many opps are qualified MTD. Then I can run a report that will show how many reps that have zero opps along with the reps that have opps.

I tired making a workflow but the field update can't cross to the user object. And I am not sure were to start on this code. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a matrix report

- Rows: Opportunity Owner
- Columns: Date qualified (grouped by month)
- Cell: Record count
- Report filter: Date_qualified__c not equal null and date_qualified in Current Calendar year

If you store the count on User, you have to clear it out every month in order to get MTD

Answer (score 0):

based on your description a basic code snippet will be something like this to update custom field on user object on invoking Opportunity trigger:

```
trigger MyCoolTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {

    List<User> userFieldUpdate = new List<User>();

    for(User u : [Select custom_field__c From User Where Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]){
        u.custom_field__c = ''//your value;
        userFieldUpdate.add(u);
    }

    if(!userFieldUpdate.isEmpty()){
        update userFieldUpdate;
    }
```

}

This code is just to give a idea of how to approach your task. Specific to your task you will need to fetch the user ID of the opportunity owner using a SOQL query and then pass it in place of 'UserInfo.getUserId()' in the above SOQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Like @crop1645 suggested, I would also go the report route. You could do something like:

1. create a new report type (Users with or without opportunities)
2. create a formula checkbox that is set to true when it meets your criteria
3. create a report with criteria that matches users you'd want to appear on the report
4. summarize the report by user and sum the field created in 2 above

[image]